# How to get a modal to open by rolling in from the left and close by rolling out to the left?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, modal-dialog, css-transitions

When I click on a navigation link (Contact), I want a modal to open by rolling in from the left.  Then clicking "close" will roll the modal out to the left.  I have tried several iterations of this with an animation where I can get the modal to roll in, but not rollout.  Then I used JS to toggle the class.  With this, the modal rolled in and out, but couldn't repeat it without reloading the page.  I am using HTML, CSS, and Vanilla JavaScript.  Any help on what I am missing would be appreciated.  Here is my current code...

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#modal1">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div>
  <section id="home"></section>
</div>

<div class="contact-modal" id="modal">
  <div class="contact-content">
    <span class="contact-close"><img class="close" img src="images/close.png" alt="Close"></span>
    <h1>Contact Modal</h1>
    <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Global Color Palette */
:root {
    --primary-color: orange;
    --secondary-color: black;
    --darkshadow-color: #000000cc;
    --white-color: #fff;
    --background-color: black;
}
  
  
/* Global Typography */
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
:root {
    --primary-font: Poppins, serif;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    html { font-size: 70%;}
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 40%;}
}
  
p {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
h1 {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}


/* General Element Styling */
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
} 

section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100em;
    height: 100vh;
}



/* Navigation Styling */
nav {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px var(--darkshadow-color);
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}


/*  Style Contact Content */
.contact-modal {  
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: rollIn;
    animation-name: rollIn;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rollIn {
    0% { 
       -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%) rotate(-180deg); 
    }
    100% { 
       -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg); 
    }
}
@keyframes rollIn {
    0% { 
       transform: translateX(-200%) rotate(-180deg); 
    }
    100% { 
       transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg); 
    }
}
}
.contact-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateZ(-50%, -50%)
}
.close {
    width: auto;   
    height: 40px; 
    float: right; 
    margin: -80px;
}

.show-contact-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate (-180deg);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
let modal = document.querySelector(".contact-modal");
let show = document.querySelector(".show-contact-modal");
let closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-contact");

function toggleModal() {
    modal.classList.toggle("show-contact-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        toggleModal();
    }
}

show.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

My code is now not working, but gives you an idea of what I am working from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Use styling for the modal that is linked by the id and with a negative left (off the page).  Create 2 classes for running the animation one to show and one to hide. Make the link call the show function and the close button call the hide function.

Here is a link to view in action: https://codepen.io/megank-playground/pen/BappdqR

and below is the code I implemented:

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><span class="link" onclick="showContact()">Contact</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div>
  <section id="home"></section>
</div>

<div class="contact-modal" id="contactmodal">
  <div class="contact-content">
    <img src="images/close.png" alt="Close" class="close" onclick="hideContact()">
    <h1>Contact Modal</h1>
    <p>(555) 555-5555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Global Color Palette */
:root {
    --primary-color: orange;
    --secondary-color: black;
    --darkshadow-color: #000000cc;
    --white-color: #fff;
    --background-color: black;
}
  
  
/* Global Typography */
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
:root {
    --primary-font: Poppins, serif;
}
html {
    font-size: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    html { font-size: 70%;}
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    html { font-size: 40%;}
}
  
p {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
h1 {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 4em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}


/* General Element Styling */
body{
    margin: 0;
    background-color: gray;
} 

section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100em;
    height: 100vh;
}



/* Navigation Styling */
nav {
    font-family: var(--primary-font);
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px var(--darkshadow-color);
  }
  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
  }
nav ul li a, span {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
.link {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*  Style Contact Content */
#contactmodal{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: -50%;
    background-color: var(--background-color);
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: 30%;
}
.contact-content {
  text-align: center;
}
.close {
    width: auto;   
    height: 40px; 
    float: right; 
    margin: -80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hideBox {
    animation: moveLeft 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 
.showBox {
   animation: moveright 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}
 
@keyframes moveLeft {
   from {left: 50%; }
   to {left: -50%; }
   0% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg); }
   100% { transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-360deg); }
}
 
@keyframes moveright {
   from {left: -50%; }
   to {left: 50%; }
   0% { transform: translateX(-100%) rotate(-360deg); }
   100% { transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg); }
}
```

JS:

```
/*  Contact Box Animation */
function showContact() {
document.getElementById("contactmodal").className = "showBox";
}

function hideContact() {
document.getElementById("contactmodal").className = "hideBox";
}
```